# Are there alternate libraries to LLVM that are built for compiling a specific IR to architecture specfic code?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, intermediate-language

I'm asking if there are libraries that provide a specification for the IR that they require and provide programs for compiling a file containing that IR down to machine code. The reasons I don't want to use LLVM are:

- I want to write the code that generates the IR myself.
- Installing the LLVM development libraries is sort of a pain in the ass when I'm working on different computers.
- I like that LLVM allows the programmer to generate the IR and not worry about compiling down to assembly, so I still want this functionality.

Comment: There are many intermediate representations and target runtimes. The most common being Java, which *many* languages uses as backend. Then there's of course .Net, also used by many languages. Both are well-documented, well-used and many of the languages (especially for the Java runtime) are open-source.

Comment: Do you mean generating the LLVM IR or any nonspecific IR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can generate LLVM IR yourself instead of using LLVM's API. LLVM IR has a convenient text representation to enable this.
- You can install just the LLVM binaries for processing the IR, rather than using their back-end libraries, so you don't need to get the development libraries set up.

Answer (score 1):

The IR code generated by your program can be then compiled to machine code with the LLVM tool [llc](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html). No development versions of LLVM libraries are required for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/libjit-doc/libjit.html) although it seems to have a slightly smaller application range (especially when it comes to analysis).